# Sort by "Date modified" does not keep track of files in subfolders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 10 at the moment. Not sure if this behavior was the same on Windows 7.

Let me explain by giving an example.
When I open Windows Explorer and go to the root of a drive I get a list of all folders on that drive. 
I would like to see in which folder new files are added recently.
So the most logical solution would be to sort by "Date modified". Right?
But apparently this does not work when the files are changed in a subfolder of that folder.

A folder can have the "Date modified" at 20/11/2018 while a subfolder would be at 27/11/2018. I would find it more logical that the root folder would also be at 27/11/2018. I'm pretty sure the behavior in Windows 7 was like this.

Does anyone recognizes this? Is this normal behavior? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behavior of Windows, and it was always this way.

The "Date modified" of an object is only changed when the object is modified.
The change of date on a child of the folder does not count as a change of
the folder.

The folder and its sub-folders have separate entries in the disk catalog table.
Since the date of the sub-folder is not contained inside the entry of the folder,
a modification of its date is not reflected in the folder's entry.
So as the folder's entry isn't modified, as a result its "Date modified" does
not change.

The "Date modified" of a folder only changes when a sub-folder is added or
deleted, or the same for any other file contained directly in the folder.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. If anyone would know a third party app that makes this possible, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It was not always this way... this is a new development. I have always arranged files I am working on by date modified because it's the easiest way to keep relevant things in front of me when switching between projects. These projects are always in subfolders and I have always arranged them by date modified. I no longer can. The answer above is misinformation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241220)

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature, data accessed, that can help you. It will show the folders according to the latest file access log.
Right-click on date modified and select 'more' then find 'data accessed'.